# Vue-chartjs : reload chart on state change

Tags: vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I’m trying to make a chart reactive to state change, I have some filters on a sidenav and a component which include chart.js component like this :

```
<tendance-chart slot="content" class="chart-wrapper" v-if="!loading" :labelsRepartitionTendance="labelsRepartitionTendance" :repartitionTendance="repartitionTendance"></tendance-chart>
```

That’s works perfecly, but I want to reload this chart when my filters change, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

When your filter changes before the function execution change loading to true and at the end change loading to false. This however is not good a good practice, basically your chart should listen for its data and re render itself every time something is changed.

Answer (score 0):

vue-chartjs ships with two mixins the reactiveDataMixin and the reactivePropMixin.
Which are adding a watcher to chartData and re-rendering oder updating the chart, if the data changes. http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data

Answer (score 0):

you must use watch and pass a setTimeout() again calling the function that handles the data.

```
 watch: {
        dataToObserve() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.functionThatHandlesData();
            }, 1000);
        }
    },
```